# MPMoviePlayerViewController observes '_serverConnectionDiedNotification'

Tags: ios, avplayer

While working with MPMoviePlayerViewController I am getting an error notification as below and the App Crashes.

> _serverConnectionDiedNotification. Info -- notification=Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11819 "Cannot Complete Action" UserInfo=0x5dfcb0 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try again later., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Complete Action}, AVPlayer = , currentTime = 0.00
>
> 2012-05-27 15:32:41.777 AnswerMania[3885:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer'

This is not happening always. I have observed all the MpMoviePlayerController Notifications but this error cannot be observed. Does it related to the Server Connection? How does the serverConnectionDiedNotification can be observed?

Comment: Plus 1. I'm facing this too and I have no idea why this is happening or how it can be resolved

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue when calendar reminder appeared while playing video. it was solved for me by not using the app audio session:

```
moviePlayer.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;
```

EDIT:
it is related to the following error, did NOT see the _serverConnectionDiedNotification:

```
AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer
```

Comment: That property is deprecated since iOS6. You should use `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error]` instead.

Comment: Nimrod, This is not the ideal solution coz, useApplicationAudioSession is deprecated in ios6. Im have the same problem. Not fixed yet :( :(